# ros_industry training, indigo, where is the code?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I can find the ros-industry training material under kinetic in github. I wonder if you can find the training code for Indigo? I just can't find them anywhere and the training material for kinetic and indigo is different too.

Also, any idea to find some good examples of descartes  planning? I know its wiki and ros_Industry training.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265383/ros_industry-training,-indigo,-where-is-the-code?/) by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the right hand side of the [ROS-Industrial github page](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training/wiki) there's a side-bar titled "Beginner Training".
It's pretty easy to miss but, if you [click on the Indigo link](http://aeswiki.datasys.swri.edu/rositraining/indigo/Exercises/) there it will take you to another wiki with code and training materials for Indigo.

There's a raft of stuff for Descartes in there but if you find anything else useful you should link it here. I've been looking for good materials on Descartes as well.

---

Originally posted by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) with karma: 147 on 2017-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2017-07-03**:
Thank you for your answer. Actually I find this page and that's the reason why I asked this question, since I can't find the code(for indigo). I know there is indigo devel under this

https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_training

But it doesn't seem to be the right one.

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2017-07-03**:
I wonder if you could point me to the right direction?

**Comment by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) on 2017-07-03**:
Sure! On the github you linked, click the branch menu in the upper left, select indigo, click into the training folder and you'll find all the code etc in the work subfolder and it's subfolders

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2017-07-03**:
lol. Thank you. I checked indigo-devel but didn't check indio.

Thank you for your help.